# Is there anyway to make this any more secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, sql-injection

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = $dbh->query($query);
```

Is there anyway to make that SELECT statement more secure using PDO? Secure as in from SQL injections anything and everything that is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Where are `$start` and `$limit` coming from

Comment: @MarkBaker The variable $start is defined depending on an if statement before it. $limit = 15

Comment: If `$limit` is always 15, then it doesn't need to be a variable

Comment: @MarkBaker, ok, thanks. But what about $start?

Comment: If you're calculating `$start` then you have absolute control over the value that you're injecting

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Is `$start` supplied by the user? Then it's most likely exploitable. Is `$start` derived from user input? Then it might be exploitable. Is it totally uncontrolled by the user? Then it's not exploitable.

Comment: for instance on SO there is a `page=` in the url (often if one paginates except for page 1). It could also come from POST to make it slightly more cumbersome to play with. But that doesn't change much. When the server gets it, it can decide if the value passed is rubbish.